# MPTT - How can I pass extra data for each node to the template?

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

Given the following `view`:

```
def comments(request):

    comments_list = Thing.objects.filter(thing_type=2)
    #Thing model extends MPTTModel 
    comments_extra_data_list = Data.objects.filter(thing__in=comments_list)
    #Data objects have data for each Thing

    return render_to_response("comments.html",
                      {'nodes':comments_list},
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I pass `comments_extra_data_list` to the template in order to display the data for each node at MPTT tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have these models:

```
class Thing(MPTTModel):
    ...
    thing_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Data(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing, related_name="data_set")
```

You can just do this in your template:

```
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <h1>{{ node }}</h1>
    {% for data in node.data_set.all %}
        {{ data.something }}
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endrecursetree %}
```

That's the naive approach. It will do one database query (fetching related `Data` objects) for each `Thing`.

If you're using django 1.4, you should prefetch the data objects in your view, so it doesn't do so many queries:

```
comments = Thing.objects.filter(thing_type=2)
comments = comments.prefetch_related('data_set')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: how'd you get on? If that's what you were looking for, don't forget to accept the answer. Then we both get improved SO reputation :)